# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,) keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

i found this error when i try to learn CNN from pyimagesearch i have tried to change the last dense from 3 into 1 but it dont resolve my prblem and i already change it into binnar_crossentroypy but its still dont work heres my code sorry for dumb and question and maybe the same question but i already do what i can do

```
ss# grab the image paths and randomly shuffle them
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"])))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)


for imagePath in imagePaths:
# load the image, resize the image to be 32x32 pixels (ignoring
# aspect ratio), flatten the image into 32x32x3=3072 pixel image
# into a list, and store the image in the data list
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
image = cv2.resize(image, (32, 32)).flatten()
data.append(image)

# extract the class label from the image path and update the
# labels list
label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
labels.append(label)

# scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0, 1]
data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

 # partition the data into training and testing splits using 75% of
 # the data for training and the remaining 25% for testing
  (trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,
   labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)



 lb =  LabelEncoder()
 trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
 testY = to_categorical(testY, 2)


 # define the 3072-1024-512-3 architecture using Keras
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(1024, input_shape=(3072,), activation="sigmoid"))
 model.add(Dense(512, activation="sigmoid"))
 model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line `trainY = to_categorical(trainY, 2)` after this line `testY = to_categorical(testY, 2)`. And change your last layer to `model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))`, because it's supposed to match a 2D matrix like your target. Also, make sure your loss function is `categorical_crossentropy`, if it isn't already.

Comment: but ihave one question, in pyimagesearch web the autho told the reader to change it into binnary crosstentropy because onle 2 classes, is it effect with my training model?

Comment: Glad I could help. From my understanding, categorical crossentropy is more flexible because it can also deal with binary classes. In contrast, binary crossentropy only works for two classes. On two classes, they do the same.

Comment: i have more question why do i need to encode my trainY with labelencoder?

Answer (score 0):

The error might come from this line:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))
```

The neural network is expecting an array *y* to have only one value. That won't have any sense, because the dimension of the *y* has two values. So, you should try with this:

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))
```

if *2* is the number of classes you are using.

Comment: ive tried to change it into model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax")) but get this error ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)